# Bluetooth is not working on my Ubuntu (Asus Rog) machine

Tags: bluetooth, asus

I have an Asus ROG zephyrus (2021).

My Ubuntu version:
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Kernel version:
5.13.0-39-generic

My bluetooth is not working; when I go to settings>bluetooth, and I enable the bluetooth, nothing is found, and when I click away and return, the Bluetooth bar is automatically turned off.

This is strange for two reasons:

- I installed Windows on the same machine, and there Bluetooth works.
- I installed the exact Ubuntu version (same kernel version too) on another machine (Acer swift), and on there Bluetooth also works

Comment: Hello. On both machines is the Bluetooth hardware the same? For example the same chip set. It is also helpful with hardware issues to know the kernel being used.  Are they the same kernel on both machines?

Comment: Nothing is strange. You probably have an unsupported by Ubuntu BT chip. On another machine you have a supported chip.

Comment: Yes, for both machines:  5.13.0-39-generic.

Comment: We need information on BT hardware. Maybe it is possible to get it working.